# Understanding Branch Protection and Metadata Restrictions: How Do They Safeguard the Target Branch?

Tags: git, github, github-rulesets

While configuring rules for a GitHub repository, I've come across the option to select a target branch for protection using a ruleset. However, I'm curious about the concept of simultaneously implementing metadata restrictions based on regex patterns for branch names. Could you explain how this combination effectively safeguards the specified target branch? Additionally, I'm uncertain whether the new restriction I added should impact the protected branch or any new branches created thereafter.

So if for example I added the `main` branch as a target branch:
[image]

And I also added a Metadata Restriction for branch names:
[image]

What is the relationship between these two features, and how do they influence each other? Does this imply that all branches originated from the `main` (default) branch must adhere to these rules and restrictions?

Comment: I haven't used this feature but I'm guessing that it's the source branches that can be merged into `main`. (Git doesn't really have an "origination branch" concept.) OR, branch names you can push in general.

Comment: If you're referring to [these options for branch names](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/available-rules-for-rulesets) then I don't think it has anything to do with protecting a target branch, unless you can *also* restrict which branches can be merged in. (I'll delete these comments after someone who knows can answer. Perhaps my comments will help someone until then.)

Comment: So, does it actually mean that the scope of this Metadata Restriction (branch name pattern matching) is repository-wide and not branch-specific?

Comment: I would think branch names would be repo wide. If you have the rule already, try pushing a new branch name that breaks the rule and see what happens. You can simply delete the branch afterwards if the push succeeds.